# How to insert values into database table from select statement SQL

Tags: sql

| ID | Name | Class | Date | Intime | Outtime | INAM | OUTPM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Paul | 1st | 29-11-2022 | Holiday | Holiday | H | H |

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    COALESCE(tt.ID, t1.ID) AS ID,
    COALESCE(tt.Name, t1.Name) AS Name,
    COALESCE(tt.Class, t1.Class) AS Class,
    tt.Date, tt.Intime, tt.Outtime, tt.INAM, tt.OUTPM   
FROM 
    stuattrecordAMPM AS t1
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM stuattrecordAMPM  
     UNION ALL
     SELECT 
         NULL, NULL, NULL, Date, Holiday_Name, Holiday_Name,
         Status, Status 
     FROM HolidayList) AS tt 
ORDER BY
    [ID]
```

In this code result showing as above table values. I want to insert values into `stuattrecordAMPM`. How can I use `INSERT` with the `SELECT` statement? Could someone help me? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are looking for select statement result output to another table input.
Please use standard sql for your needs.

```
  insert into target_table(id,name)
        select id,name from my_table;
```